# How to get the data in Runtime and execute the code in unix

Tags: bash, unix

First the user will call a file name Time.sh and enter two data, namely StartTime , EndTime. I have the code in Time.sh file to extract the data between the StartTime and EndTime. I am using the follwing code.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter StartTime:" StartTime
read -p "Enter EndTime:" EndTime
awk -v StartTime="$StartTime" -v EndTime="$EndTime" -f Script.sh Test.log
```

So in the bash I will something like below,

```
$ ./Time.sh
Enter Start Time :(User will enter StartTime. Example:01:04:22)
Enter End Time : (User will enter EndTime. Example:01:05:22)
```

I want to simplyfy it for the user like, the user should type all three data in a single line like,

```
Time.sh 01:04:22 01:05:55
```

How can I modify to get the same result? Please Help.

Comment: Why do you call your Awk script `Script.sh`.  If you use a file name extension, it would seem more conventional to use `.awk`; but Unix doesn't particularly care, so you are only confusing humans.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Added input validation**

You can use the command line arguments as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
StartTime=$1
EndTime=$2

if [[ "$StartTime" > "$EndTime" ]]; then
    echo "StartTime cannot be greater than EndTime"
else
    awk -v StartTime="$StartTime" -v EndTime="$EndTime" -f Script.sh Test.log 
fi
```

And then run it by: `./Time.sh 01:04:22 01:05:55`

Comment: Thank you @Avihoo Mamka.I have used the following code to check if the starttime is greater than endtime. But i cannot execute the else part. Whatever time i entered, it is showing only the echo part. Is there any mistake in the syntax.  `if [ "$1" > "$2" ]; then
     echo  "StartTime cannot be greater than EndTime"     
else
awk -v StartTime="$StartTime" -v EndTime="$EndTime" -f Script.sh Test.log
fi`

Comment: I edited my answer, and it worked for me. check this.

Comment: Pay attention, I edited again, changed `>` to `-gt`.

Comment: You can do: `if [ "$#" -eq "3"]; then echo "3 params" else echo "less than 3 params" fi`

Comment: Show me the arguments you use for the scripts that gets only the else part, and check that you're using `-gt` and not `>`.

Comment: I think  `-gt` is used only for integers. I am getting ` line 5: [: 01:07:14: integer expression expected` error if I enter a startime greater than endtime.

Comment: Fixed that. Added double `[[]]` to the `if`

Comment: I have used `if [[ "$#" -ne "3" ]]; then 
echo "Enter All three parameters"
fi` this code before the IF part.But I am getting both the echo part in the output. Should I have to use else if?

Comment: No, you should add `exit 1` after the echo of the error, to quit the script with an error code indicates there's a problem.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
StartTime=$1
EndTime=$2
if [[ "$#" -ne "3" ]]; then 
{
echo "Enter All three parameters"
exit 1
}
fi

if [[ "$StartTime" > "$EndTime" ]]; then
{
    echo "StartTime cannot be greater than EndTime"
    exit 2
}
else
    awk -v StartTime="$StartTime" -v EndTime="$EndTime" -f Script.sh Test.log 
fi`. Is this code is correct? But I am getting`Enter All Three parametrs` for all conditions. Also I have to check if Script.sh and Test.log files exits or not.